# how to get list of javascript methods used/called in an individual page?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Is there a way in javascript or any tool through which I can find list of javascript methods used/called in an individual page

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want to find out which functions were actively used, you can use [Firebug](http://getfirebug.com)'s profiling feature.

Cick "Profile" in its console tab, reload the page, use the page in whatever way you need to, then click "Profile" again to get a listing of the functions which were used, how many times they were called and how long they took.

If you want to trigger profiling on a particular section of your code, you can use calls to  the Firebug console API - `console.profile()` to start profiling and `console.profileEnd()` to stop profiling.

If you want to see what's available for use on the page, switch to Firebug's DOM tab, use its configuration dropdown to uncheck every option but "Show User-defined Properties" and "Show User-defined Functions" and you'll be able to easily see everything that's been added to the global scope by your JavaScript.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use eclipse kind of editor or browser based script tools like fire bug and chrome default developer tool.